# How to allow all users to run this SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, openrowset

Some context: I am trying to upload data from Comcast into our database.  Comcast sends the data in a macro-enabled workbook with file extension ".xlsm" which is disgusting. To circumvent this, I setup a power automate desktop flow to open the XLSM files and save them as XLSX files.  I then run this query under an INSERT on our reporting server to get the data into the DB:

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 
   'Excel 12.0 Xml;Database=\\COMPANYNAME\company\customer\Comcast\Comcast.xlsx;', Sheet1$);
```

The only problem is, I'd like this to be automated.  So I setup a cloud power automate flow to run the desktop flow and then execute a stored procedure in SQL Server.  My flow receives the same error I do on my machine as well as any user outside of the COMPANYNAME\administrator session in SSMS on our reporting server:

> Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
> The OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
> Msg 7303, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
> Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)".

It has been very difficult to research this issue as there seem to be many possible causes.  I'm no IT wizard but I know enough to be dangerous.  Thank you in advance for your time and help and I eagerly await your response!

Comment: are you sure that the path can be reached? This looks like the xslx can not be loaded, is NULL for the OPENROWSET, this gives your error. so out it where all users can reach it

Comment: Hi nbk, I am sure the path can be reached because this exact code when copy+pasted into the reporting server works.  Also, to test, I moved the XLSX file to the C drive of the reporting server, updated the path and ran the code again -- same error message on my machine but it works on the reporting server.

Comment: Can you not open the xlsm file in Power Automate and send/insert the data directly to SQL? You have to setup the SQL communication first. I run a task to insert data from MS Forms directly into SQL so I know it's possible.

Comment: Tim: that is a good idea.  I'd like to make this option work if possible since the infrastructure is already there, it just needs to work lol

Comment: all program, especially automated runs with special user priviliges, so you could chekc with filemon what actually happens

Comment: Yikes, if you're going to do that much work on the XLS*, I'd just export it to a CSV and use BCP.

Comment: Hello viewer.  thank you to everyone who posted input.  I ended up going with Plan B.  I setup Power Automate to just read the XLSM file and write to a CSV file separated by semi-colons because Comcast had commas in some Caller IDs.  Then updated the stored procedure to use a simple CSV bulk insert, which cloud automate runs fine.